# In React with Ag Grid, I want to export the grid to PDF. For simple data I am able to do it with pdfmake, but for tree data it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, pdfmake

I have tree data (hierarchy) in rowData and children in columnDefs. How to export this type of complex report to pdf?